# Extracting Tags/text between pipes ("|") and counting them

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with a video name and their tags (words between pipes ("|) ).

For example:

```
// Video_name       //           Tags         //

// -------- --------// -------------- --------//

// Nba highlights   // NBA | Jordan | America //

// Basketball's best// USA | Nba              //

//   Usa Video      //      *no tags*         //
```

I need, somehow, to receive the total number of used tags.

```
NBA - 2
Usa - 1
Jordan - 1
```

and so on.

Every video has a different amount of tags, and some don't have any. I can't know in advance what tags there will be.

Using Snowflake but also SQL is fine.

Comment: What have you tried to far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the [split_to_table](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html) function for this. Here is an example with your data:

#### Set up sample data:

```sql
-- Create a sample table
create or replace table test_table
(
    video_name varchar,
    tags   varchar
);

-- Insert some sample data
insert overwrite into test_table
values ('Nba highlights', 'NBA | Jordan | America'),
       ('Basketball''s best', 'USA | Nba'),
       ('Usa Video', '*no tags*');

-- The table looks like: 
-- +-----------------+----------------------+
-- |VIDEO_NAME       |TAGS                  |
-- +-----------------+----------------------+
-- |Nba highlights   |NBA | Jordan | America|
-- |Basketball's best|USA | Nba             |
-- |Usa Video        |*no tags*             |
-- +-----------------+----------------------+
```

#### Use `split_to_table` in a select to get the results:

```sql
-- Run the query to get the grouping of tags
select
    UPPER(TRIM(split.VALUE)) tag_name,
    count(1)
from test_table, table(split_to_table(test_table.tags, '|')) split
group by tag_name
;
```

The above query gives the following results:

```
+---------+--------+
|TAG_NAME |COUNT(1)|
+---------+--------+
|NBA      |2       |
|JORDAN   |1       |
|AMERICA  |1       |
|*NO TAGS*|1       |
|USA      |1       |
+---------+--------+
```

Comment: Amazing!  Many Thanks!!! Is there something also for SQL?

Comment: No probs. I'm not sure how you'd do this easily with standard SQL unfortunately, most major database dialects will likely have some sort of proprietary function like split_to_table.